# how to style this via css in Bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'd like to override the nav link-color in a role=presentation for a nav list. I'd like to set it to yellow. I am only looking to select this one instance.

the html:

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
  <li role="presentation"><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
```

I have:

```
li[role=presentation] a:link{
  color:yellow;
}
```

But this doesn't work. Any ideas on how to get this to work?

Comment: http://www.bootply.com/1DNGQRAP5m Can you explain what you're trying to do ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

take the `:link` out of your css selector

```css
li[role=presentation] a{
  color:yellow;
}
```

```html
<ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
    <li role="presentation"><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
    <li role=""><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
li[role="presentation"] a{
  color: yellow !important;
}
```